# Why is the date input width on Android default browser is 3px less than text input width

Tags: css, html

I am trying to use the native date input for a HTML5 form, the width is the same on every browser except for the Android default browser.  Is this a known bug, and if so, how do I work around it as I do not know how to only target the Android default browser.

I have created a JSFiddle to demonstrate the issue.  All of the fields should just touch the red lines on the right and left.

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="text1" name="text1" placeholder="text input" />
    <input type="date" id="date1" name="date1" placeholder="date input" />
    <input type="text" id="text2" name="text2" placeholder="text input" />
</form>
```

CSS:

```
html, body, form, input {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body {
    margin:50px;
}
form {
    width: 202px;
}
form {
    border:1px solid red;
    border-top:none;
    border-bottom:none;
}
input {
    width: 200px;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ntyjG/